# Prometheus has so many DOWN metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I just installed Prometheus on my k8s cluster, when I go to targets page, it shows me so many `DOWN` state in scrape job result.

[image: Prometheus]

What should I do to get the `UP` result from Prometheus scrape? Did I miss something when setup?

Comment: Please post the link you used to setup this. I believe , some of those services which are down do not expose metrics by default, so you will have to explicitly turn on metrics on each one of them by searching on how to do it for each one of them.

Comment: @fatcook I followed https://supergiant.io/blog/monitoring-your-kubernetes-deployments-with-prometheus/ tutorial.

Comment: Does kubernetes default services don't expose their own metrics endpoint?

Comment: Maybe not , you might want to check those services/pods configuration/yaml to see if they have exposed the metrics endpoint or not

Comment: I checked my ingress-nginx yaml and it was found:
`annotations:    
        prometheus.io/port: '10254'     
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'`

Comment: But you seem to have been scraping on some other port as per your screenshot

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had wrong prometheus configmap, and now it seems work already.

Comment: But there are no nginx_ingress_controller_* query available, only nginx_*.

Answer (score 1):

As @Justinus Hermawan mentioned in the comments, the problem has occurred due to some Prometheus scrapes misconfiguration, which has to be solved by adjusting appropriate Prometheus [configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) in relevant Kubernetes `ConfigMap`. Evaluating the answer for any further contributors research.